# I am unable to use wp search-replace I am getting an error as Error establishing a database connection

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am using mamp as my local server and PHPMyAdmin.

I am trying to set up a deployed WordPress website on my local machine I was able to get all the database details and the WordPress files. And I added all the WordPress files in the htdocs folder and also I uploaded the database files to my PHPMyAdmin I created a new user and a password.

this is the command which I used to replace the deployed URL with the local URL.

`wp search-replace 'https://test.com' 'http://localhost:8888/vascari' --dry-run`

But I am getting this error

`Error establishing a database connection.`

I checked on multiple documentation all of them were mentioning to check the `wp-config.php` details but all of them were correct the reason was that I manage to set up a WordPress website from scratch using those credentials.

The php version that I am using on mamp and the local machine is 7.4

the local host apache port is 8888 the MySQL port is 8889.

can someone help me to resolve this Because I am going through this for the lase one week thank you...